# SQL Compact Edition (CE) and password complexity requirements

Tags: windows-7, passwords, sql-server-ce, group-policy

In Windows 7 we have group policies enforcing password complexity requirements which demands "better" password for SQL server express.

Does this impact SQL CE as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not affect SQL Server Compact...